# Expanding $\frac{1}{1-z-z^2}$ to a power series.

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, analysis, power-series, generating-functions

How would you expand the analytic function $$\frac{1}{1-z-z^2}$$ to a series of the form $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k \, \, ?$$

Comment: Start with partial fractions.

Comment: i can't get $1-z-z^2$ to factorise?

Comment: Sure you can. $z^2+z-1=0$ has the roots $\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. Call these $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Then $z^2+z-1=(z-\alpha)(z-\beta)$.

Comment: A [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/776855/73025).

Answer (score 13):

*Hint.* Consider $$(1-z-z^2)\left(\sum a_kz^k\right)=1$$ as a formal polynomial equation, where the RHS is the polynomial $1=1+0z+0z^2+\dotsb$.  Multiplying out the LHS and equating with the RHS term by term, we find that $$\eqalign{a_0\,&=&\;1\cr -a_0+a_1\,&=&\;0\cr -a_0 - a_1 + a_2\,&=&\;0 \cr -a_1 - a_2 + a_3 \,&=&\;0\cr -a_2 - a_3 + a_4 \,&=&\;0 \cr \vdots\;\;\; &&\;\, \vdots\cr}$$
which we can rearrange to
$$\eqalign{a_0\,&=&\;1\\a_1\,&=&\;a_0\\a_2\,&=&\;a_0 + a_1\\ a_3\,&=&\;a_1 + a_2\\ a_4\,&=&\;a_2 + a_3 \\  \vdots \;\;&&\;\;\vdots}$$
Does this sequence look familiar$\ldots$?

Comment: Very nicely done! (+1)

Comment: And using this and the comments in the question, you can get the closed form sequence of fibonacci series.

Answer (score 4):

Write $1-z-z^2=(a-z)(z+b)$ and and using this, write the partial fraction of
$$
\frac 1{1-z-z^2}=\frac 1{a+b}\left(\frac 1 {a-z} +\frac 1 {b+z} \right)
$$

Comment: how do you calculate what $a$ and $b$ are?

Answer (score 3):

Three ways:

- Write as partial fractions:
  $$
  \frac{1}{1 - z - z^2}
    = \frac{1}{(1 - \tau z) (1 - \overline{\tau} z)}
    = \frac{\tau}{\sqrt{5} (1 - \tau z)} 
        - \frac{\overline{\tau}}{\sqrt{5} (1 -\overline{\tau} z)}
  $$
  Here $\tau$ is the positive root of $r^2 - r - 1 = 0$, $\overline{\tau}$ the negative one ($\tau$s are zeros of the denominator $1 - z - z^2$). That is:
  \begin{align}
  \tau            &= \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \\
  \overline{\tau} &= \frac{-1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}
  \end{align}
  This is a pair of geometric series:
  $$
  [z^n] \frac{1}{1 - z - z^2}
    = \frac{\tau^{n + 1} - \overline{\tau}^{n + 1}}{\sqrt{5}}
  $$
- Expand:
  \begin{align}
  \frac{1}{1 - z(1 + z)}
    &= \sum_{r \ge 0} z^r (1 + z)^r \\
    &= \sum_{r \ge 0} z^r \sum_{0 \le s \le r} \binom{r}{s} z^s \\
  [z^n] \frac{1}{1 - z - z^2}
    &= \sum_{r + s = n} \binom{r}{s} \\
    &= \sum_{0 \le k \le n} \binom{k}{n - k}
  \end{align}
- Recognize the generating function of the Fibonacci numbers:
  $$
  F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1, F_{n + 2} = F_{n + 1} + F_n
  $$
  gives:
  $$
  F(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} F_n z^n = \frac{z}{1 - z - z^2}
  $$
  so that:
  $$
  \frac{1}{1 - z - z^2}
    = \frac{F(z) - F_0}{z}
    = \sum_{n \ge 0} F_{n + 1} z^n
  $$